# Check if an element contains a class by regex with classList

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a simple list of elements looking like this:

```
<ul class="items-list">
  <li class="item item-1"></li>
  <li class="item item-2"></li>
  <li class="item item-3"></li>
  <li class="item item-4"></li>
</ul>
```

I select the list by

```
items = document.getElementsByClassName('items-list')[0]
```

Finally inside a `for..in` loop I want to extract class name that is `'item-*'`.
As I want to make it without jQuery or other libraries, I wonder how I can do it in the most elegant way, something like

```
if (item.classList.contains('item-.*'))
  do_something()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check if [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (ES5) class matches your regExp:

```
if(item.className.split(' ').some(function(c){ return /item-.*/.test(c); }))
  do_something()
/* or */
if([].some.call(item.classList, function(c){ return /item-.*/.test(c); }))
  do_something()
```

Or, in ES6, using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions), you can simplify that to

```
if(item.className.split(' ').some(c => /item-.*/.test(c)))
  do_something()
/* or */
if([].some.call(item.classList, c => /item-.*/.test(c)))
  do_something()
```

But of course, if you want maximum performance, use a loop:

```
for (var i=0, l=item.classList.length; i<l; ++i) {
    if(/item-.*/.test(item.classList[i])) {
        do_something();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use regex to test if the className contains `item-`

```js
if (/item-/.test(item.className)) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Works smooth :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('items-list')[0];
  for (var i = 0, len = items.children.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (/item-/.test(items.children[i].className)) {
      console.log(items.children[i].className);
      // or doSomething();
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tcs6b/ perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Since no answer mentioned `Array.from()`, I'll go with my own version:

```js
// now you have a real array, so you can call any Array method
const classNames = Array.from(item.classList);
// now you can perform your checks on the array
const classNameHasGivenPattern = classNames.some(className => /item-/.test(className));
if (classNameHasGivenPattern) {
  // ...
}
```